# concatenating two commands in same system() call

Tags: c, windows

```
int main()
{
  // system("start cd i:");            //1. changing to I: but again going back to c:
     system(" dir i: >>d:\txt.txt");   //2. "Access denied."
     getch();
return 0;
}
```

Could someone please explain the output generated by this code in the statements one and two.
And please suggest how to concatenate these two commands in same `system()` call.

Comment: Write a batch file, and start it?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QTLAtlo.png?1

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/JozGWkl.png?1

Comment: @alk can you please elaborat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cd` command is to change the directory of the **current** drive.

To change the drive just issue the drive letter itself followed by `:`.

So to switch to drive `I:`, issue:

```
I:
```

The command interpreter allows to concatenate two commands using a `&`:

```
system("command1 & command2");
```

Which in your case would become:

```
system("I: & dir >>d:\\txt.txt")
```

---

Alternativly you could add each command you want to have execute by the command processor to a text file, one command per line, than name the file to `something.bat` and just call this from the command line. Each line will then be execute by the command processor.

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file

Comment: but it doesnt seem to do what its supposed to do  , for example :        system("echo command is working > d:\\echo.txt  ; dir i:     >>d:\\echo.txt "); is giving a peculiar output i.e     "  command is working   ; dir i:  ".. though its working properly with & instead of ;.

Answer (score 7):

```
system(" dir i: >>d:\txt.txt");
```

should be

```
system(" dir i: >>d:\\txt.txt");
```

otherwise you try to create a file "tab" followed by "xt.txt" which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate two commands with an `&`.

```
system("cd i: &  dir i: >>d:\\txt.txt");
```

Also note that you need `\\` instead of `\` in your path - the `\` needs to be escaped.